# Como posso somar o valor do resultado ao valor anterior?

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber,como faço para somar na variável `res` o valor da sequencia e depois printa-lo? como por exemplo, entrar com o valor de `N` igual a 2 e conseguir na saída o valor 2.5?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int N,i;
    float res;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    for( i = 1 ; i <= N; i++)
    {
        res = (float)i/((N - i) + 1);
    }
    printf("%.4f\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer isso, você pode utilizar o operador [`+=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6z5yhhs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (*atribuição de adição*) para acumular o resultado e inicializar a variável `res`. O código deve ficar assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    int N, i;
    float res = 0;
    puts("Digite um valor: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for( i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        res += (float)i/((N - i) + 1);
    }
    printf("%.2f\n", res); // 2.50
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/nGN9XM)</kbd>